# How to check pvalues and beta estimates for external variables used in facebook prophet for forecasting in python

Tags: python-3.x, forecasting, facebook-prophet

I am using facebook Prophet for multivariate forecasting which has an objecting of forecasting prices. My target variable is affected by n number of external variables too.

I am using add_regressor of fb prophet library to add these variables  but cant figure out a way to know the strength of these variable in forecasting y.

Can we get a summary which displays pvalues , beta estimates , standard error etc.